# Podman(1): How to route requests between the HOST and PODs attached to a podman network (rootless)

Tags: podman, redhat-containers

Let me use a real example to aid this question.

Using `rootless podman(1)`, I start a tiny `Spark` cluster within it's own `Pod` using the following script, which works well:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

podman network create --subnet 192.168.10.0/24 --gateway 192.168.10.1 mynet

podman pod create \
    --name=spark \
    --network=mynet \
    --share net \
    --publish 7077:7077 \
    --publish 8080:8080

podman run \
    --detach \
    --pod=spark \
    --name=master01 \
    --hostname spark \
    --restart always \
    --env SPARK_MODE=master \
    --env SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no \
    --env SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no \
    --env SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no \
    --env SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no \
    --add-host spark:127.0.0.1 \
    --add-host worker01:127.0.0.1 \
    docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest

podman run \
    --detach \
    --pod=spark \
    --name=worker01 \
    --hostname worker01 \
    --restart always \
    --env SPARK_MODE=worker \
    --env SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077 \
    --env SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4G \
    --env SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8 \
    --env SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no \
    --env SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no \
    --env SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no \
    --env SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no \
    --add-host spark:127.0.0.1 \
    --add-host worker01:127.0.0.1 \
    docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
```

Following is an image of the `SparkUI`.

(`Note`: This question uses `Spark` as an aid, but is not itself about `Spark`).

[image]

See lower-left corner of the browser image. Hovering the mouse over the only available `Spark worker` link (beneath `Worker id`), notice that the URL resolves to `192.168.10.2`, which is a valid `Pod IP-Address` falling within the `podman network` created above.

However, clicking that URL will, of course, hang because that `Pod IP-Address` is not reachable from the `HOST`. With `docker(1)` (not `podman(1)`) there's a gateway mechanism to routes requests between `guest containers` and the `Host`.

How is this accomplished with `podman(1)`?

A few other points to help:

- This is an example `Spark Pod`. There are additional `Pod`s that attach that same `pod network`: `mynet`
- I don't want to publish extra ports, because that will break anyway once you go deeper into the `UI`. More importantly, doing that defeats the purpose of `Pod`s, which isolate conflicting ports from one another. Rather, I need to understand how to "gateway" these requests.
- Finally, I'm humbled because I thought I knew `podman(1)` quite well. `LoL`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANSWER**:

In speaking with the `podman(1)` team over at [GitHub](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/10815), the scenario above (and similar) will always be problematic because `rootless networking` does not have privileges to configure `bridge networking` that could permit the port-forwarding needed.

So there are two alternatives:

1. Do the same thing above, but using `rootful podman(1)` (`rootful containers)`. Basically, run things with `sudo(1)`.
2. Use `host` mode networking, which places all containers into the same `network namespace` as the `HOST` (basically bare-metal naked) -- whether or not those containers were launched inside a `Pod`. Consequently, use of `Pod`s with `host` mode no longer offers network isolation, but they still offer the convenience of treating containers within them as a group (for example `start` and `stop` them as a group). Also, the `--publish` option no longer applies because everything co-exists at the `HOST` (top) level; and so the notion of `inner` and `outer` ports don't exist.

A nice little tutorial for `rootless container/host` networking with `podman(1)` can be found [here](https://www.tutorialworks.com/podman-host-networking/).